# Measures to study working memory level related to physical activity

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, experimental-psychology, working-memory, neuropsychology

I want to do a study on the effect of physical exercise on working memory. Can you suggest measures for working memory assessment that differentiate levels of memory functioning amongst "normal" adults?

Answer (score 2):

A very common test of working memory is the [N-back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-back).

In the N-back, the subject needs to remember what happened some number (N) of steps earlier. For example, imagine seeing the following numbers one at a time on a computer screen. Your task is to press a key whenever the number on the screen is the same as the number that was there 3 steps earlier:

1 4 5 2 6 3 4 5 6 **4** 2 5 3 **2**.

The numbers in bold are when the subject should respond.

There are many variations of the n-back, and it is easy to adjust the difficulty of the test by changing how many steps back subjects need to remember.